# Birthdays (dates) between two months

Tags: mysql

I want to allow the ability to find people with birthdays in the next 30 days. So if today was the 11th January, I want to find people that's birthday falls on the 11th Jan till the 10th Feb.

My code that seems to work is

```
DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') >= '01-11' AND DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') <= '02-10')
```

Howeever if the date was the 11th December, it would show like this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') >= '12-11' AND DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') <= '01-10')
```

And obviously that wont work because it's trying to find birthdays between 12-11 and 01-10...

How would I make this search between the two dates correctly even though the second date is smaller than the first date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be careful with strings and integers when you're handling dates and times and use the functions that exist to manipulate them.

```
SELECT . FROM .
WHERE MAKEDATE( YEAR(CURDATE()), DAYOFYEAR(birthday) 
    BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY )
OR MAKEDATE( YEAR(CURDATE())+1, DAYOFYEAR(birthday) 
    BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY )
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`datediff`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function returns the number of days between two dates. [`now`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) returns the current date and time.

```
SELECT birthday
FROM dates
WHERE datediff( MAKEDATE( YEAR(NOW()) , DAYOFYEAR(birthday) ) , NOW())
     BETWEEN 0 AND 30
   OR datediff( MAKEDATE( YEAR(NOW())+1 , DAYOFYEAR(birthday) ) , NOW())
     BETWEEN 0 AND 30;
```

If `birthday` *has* already happened, `datediff(birthday,NOW())` would return a negative number. Therefore, we need to get values [`between`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) 0 and 30.

Comment: but if you compare now with a birthday from lets say 20 years ago, that wouldn't work, right?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you generate the query, but in the case where the day you want to query for is >= '12-2' you simply would have to swap the `AND` with an `OR`.

A bit tricky if you want to do it in a single query using `NOW()`, but simple if you assamble the query in php or something simmilar.

---

If you want a single query this should do:

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE
(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') < '12-2' AND DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), '%m-%d')) OR 
(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') >= '12-2' AND (DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') OR DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), '%m-%d')))
```

It's a hell of a query, but I think it does what you need:
If today is before the december 1st, take all dates that are >= today `AND` <= today + 30,
else take all dates >= today `OR` <= today + 30 (what is in the next year in that case)